# iPhone - How may I know where my user is going to into a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, events, uiwebview, hyperlink, touch

Web presenting a website in a UIWebView, the user can touch links.

When testing `[[webView.request URL] absoluteString]`in `didFailLoadWithError` or `webViewDidStartLoad`, it returns the previous url. The touched url is shown in `webViewDidFinishLoad`

If the user touches a link, and the connection fails, how may I know where he was going to as `webViewDidFinishLoad` is not triggered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately after the link is tapped, `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` is called in your delegate. That gives you a chance to inspect the request and what kind of navigation action triggered it (link, back/forward, form post...).

Comment: I think he was asking if connection failed to load completely delegate wouldn't notify didFailLoadWithError, so if connection fails to complete request after webViewDidFinishLoad, how to capture that URL that caused it."If the user touches a link, and the connection fails, how may I know where he was going to as webViewDidFinishLoad is not triggered ?" From last two lines that is what he mean't I thought.

Comment: When webView:shouldStartLoad... is called, you remember the URL in a variable, when it fails to load, it is the last URL you remembered that caused the problem...